# Uploading Google Earth historical Imagery to QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, google-earth

Is there any way that I could upload historical Google Earth imagery to QGIS, instead of saving them one by one and importing/Georeferencing them?

Comment: Try to see if this two plugins can help, Google Earth Engine and 
Google Earth Engine Data Catalog

Comment: Hello, I installed both the plugins but I cannot understand how they "work"... I have watched several videos, but still cannot manage to use them... Could you kindly provide a tutorial?

Comment: AikK try this https://github.com/giswqs/qgis-earthengine-examples